# Self intersecting polygons after import into Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth, qgis

There are some unexpected artifacts when importing the merged polygons ("dissolve all" function in QGIS) into Google Earth as KML or SHP.
I also tried merging the polygons using the C# Clipper library, but exactly the same result.

Polygons before "dissolve all"
[image]

Result in QGIS:
[image]

This is how it looks in Google Earth:
[image]

It seems like the problem in Google Earth is caused by self-intersecting polygons.
**Update**: When I ran "Geometry Tools > Simplify Geometries" in QGIS it fixed the self-intersecting polygons somehow. In the results it said it simplified from 78319 points to 76322, but it is still unclear what it actually changed.

Comment: From my experience Google Earth is surprisingly buggy, maybe there is no quick fix. Does changing the viewpoint in the GUI change the visible intersections?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your images it appears you haven't transformed the projection of your data. (the circles are more perfect in google earth and is more elliptical in your QGIS image). Try to re project your data to WGS84

Comment: When I made the screenshot the projection in QGIS wasn't set to WGS84. So when I changed it to that the display in QGIS itself is correct. When I exported I already selected WGS 84, which Google Earth can handle.